# Subscription Database for Web App: How to Determine the Expiration date?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

[image]

I am confused about how to design a database structure that suits the needs of the application I am building, I really hope to get the answer here.

So, I'm creating databases for web applications, where users who want to use our application they need to subscribe first, however for new users they can use it for free for 7 days starting from the start date of account registration.

The application that I created here is used to remote a device, so that the application works properly, the user needs a VPN.

So, all users will get a VPN account and can access my application according to the active period of the plan they are using.

I am a beginner in the world of databases, this is the database structure that pops into my head.

I'm confused about the expiration date,

**1. How do I update the subscription expiration date based on the package that the user selects?**

**2. How do I update the subscription expiration date if the user renews the subscription before the previous package expires?**

Other programs also need information whether the user is in the subscription period or not, this information is used to delete the VPN account and prevent users from accessing the main application.

If you were working on this project, how would you structure your database?

I appreciate all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't "update" (in terms of materializing) anything at all. When a user tries to connect (or use the application or the like), check if there's a subscription that isn't expired by adding the time period the subscription is valid to the point in time the subscription began and check if that is before now.